# switch case in dart is not working properly

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-html

I am trying to use switch case but it is behaving weirdly. For some inputs it is working and for some inputs it is not working. I checked the input values and found that they are good for the condition to be satisfied. Please help. I am new to flutter and dart.

I tried to achieve this with if-else if. Even that did not work for me.

```
    List<String> lstNames = List<String>();
    lstNames.addAll(["Dividends INR", "Payout Ratio % *", "Operating Cash Flow INR Mil", "Cap Spending INR Mil", "Free Cash Flow INR Mil"]);
    for(String ItemHeading in lstNames){

    switch (ItemHeading) {
      case '' :
        break;
      case 'Dividends INR':
        {/*Doing something.*/}
        break;
      case 'Payout Ratio % *':
        {/*Doing something.*/}
        break;
      case 'Operating Cash Flow INR Mil':
        {/*Doing something.*/}
        break;
      case 'Cap Spending INR Mil':
        {/*Doing something.*/}
        break;
      case 'Free Cash Flow INR Mil':
        {/*Doing something.*/}
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

In the above code, based on the strings in lstNames I am trying to run the switch case. The string values contained by Elements in lstRows are {Dividends INR, Payout Ratio % *, Operating Cash Flow INR Mil, Cap Spending INR Mil, Free Cash Flow INR Mil}. The case for 'Payout Ratio % *' works. For the rest, it just skips/jumps to the next case and exits. Please help. Let me know if anymore information is required for debugging this.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
`addAll()` takes an `iterable`

```
lstNames.addAll(["Dividends INR", "Payout Ratio % *", "Operating Cash Flow INR Mil", "Cap Spending INR Mil", "Free Cash Flow INR Mil"]);
```

put items inside a list.

---

You are using wrong comments

`//` comments the whole line as well as the closing `}`

`/*   */` to be used

```
  case 'Dividends INR':
    {/*Doing something.*/}
    break;
  case 'Payout Ratio % *':
    {/*Doing something.*/}
    break;
```

[image: dartlang]

Comment: Also, there is no need for a `break` after `default` case.

Comment: I have made the edits. The comments were only given to replace the business logic. The problem of switch case is still there. It is working for 'Payout Ratio % *' and not for rest of the cases. Please help.

Comment: also, it looks like you have a new line inside `Operating Cash Flow INR Mil` which is causing the problem.

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. That addAll() is also for hiding the business logic. I have made the edit. The list lstNames is fine. Problem is when the control goes inside the swich case, I can clearly see in debug that the value contained by ItemHeading is a case constant value which should satisfy it and the case should be executed. Still it is jumping the case and going to the next case.

Comment: did you correct the newline thing mentioned in my earlier comment?

Comment: This piece of code is working just fine. But the same piece of code with my business logic is jumping the case statements. I have no idea why. I tried .compareTo() as well but still it wont enter the case statements.

Comment: Note that the `{}` is not needed: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#switch-and-case.

Comment: This code is correct. The problem, as explored in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937845/string-comparison-not-working-for-text-received-from-web-scraping is that the `ItemHeading` string contains different characters than the code expects. So, swtich does work.