# String comparison not working for text received from web scraping

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-html

I am comparing text received from web scraping with hardcoded text in my code. The two texts are identical. No Capital-Small error. They are identical but still the comparison fails. I am sharing a part of my code.
The problem is between the lines 47 to 56. Between these lines, the string comparison in if else blocks fails. The values provided for these blocks are perfectly fine values which should ideally satisfy the condition. The if condition at 49 gets satisfied for some reason and the other if conditions don't get satisfied. This behaviour is so weird. The same code when converted in Java runs and works fine without a glitch executing all the if conditions. Please have a look and help. Thanks.

I have tried this with switch case as well but failed with it too.

```
 import 'package:http/http.dart';
 import 'package:html/parser.dart';
 import 'package:html/dom.dart';
 import 'dart:convert';
 class Worker{

 static final String OperatingCashFlowINRMil = 'Operating Cash Flow INR Mil';
 static final String CapSpendingINRMil = 'Cap Spending INR Mil';
 static final String FreeCashFlowINRMil = 'Free Cash Flow INR Mil';
 static final String DividendsINR = 'Dividends INR';
 static final String DividendPayoutRatio = 'Payout Ratio % *';
 static Map<String,String> _RequestHeaders = Map<String,String>();

 static void fetchData() async
 {
 String MSUrlToGetFinancialData =
    "https://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getFinancePart.html?&callback=jsonp1553353302056&t=0P0000AX98&region=ind&culture=en-US&version=SAL&cur=&order=desc&_=1553353302079";
Client client = Client();

Response response2 = await client.get(MSUrlToGetFinancialData,
    headers: getRequestHeaders());

var FinDataResponse = response2.body;

FinDataResponse = FinDataResponse.replaceAll("jsonp1553353302056(", "");
FinDataResponse =
    FinDataResponse.substring(0, FinDataResponse.length - 1);

JsonDecoder jsonDecoder = JsonDecoder();
var FinDataJson = jsonDecoder.convert(FinDataResponse);
String FinDataString = FinDataJson["componentData"];
Element FinDataDoc = parse(FinDataString).body;
Element DataTable = FinDataDoc.querySelector("table");
List<Element> lstYears = DataTable.querySelector("thead")
    .querySelector("tr")
    .querySelectorAll("th");
List<Element> lstRows =
DataTable.querySelector("tbody").querySelectorAll("tr");

Map<String, Element> mapItemNameToElement = Map<String, Element>();

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////0
for (Element e in lstRows) {
  String ItemHeading = e.children[0].text.trim().toString();
  print(ItemHeading);//The identical values which can satisfy the following conditions can be seen printed here.

  if (ItemHeading == DividendsINR) {//This condition does not get satisfied even when the ItemHeading value is identical.
    mapItemNameToElement.putIfAbsent(DividendsINR, () => e);
  } else if (ItemHeading == DividendPayoutRatio) {//This condition gets satisfied.
    mapItemNameToElement.putIfAbsent(DividendPayoutRatio, () => e);
  } else if (ItemHeading == OperatingCashFlowINRMil) {//This condition does not get satisfied even when the ItemHeading value is identical.
    mapItemNameToElement.putIfAbsent(OperatingCashFlowINRMil, () => e);
  } else if (ItemHeading == CapSpendingINRMil) {//This condition does not get satisfied even when the ItemHeading value is identical.
    mapItemNameToElement.putIfAbsent(CapSpendingINRMil, () => e);
  } else if (ItemHeading == FreeCashFlowINRMil) {//This condition does not get satisfied even when the ItemHeading value is identical.
    mapItemNameToElement.putIfAbsent(FreeCashFlowINRMil, () => e);
  }
}
}


static Map<String,String> getRequestHeaders()
{
if(_RequestHeaders.length == 0)
{
  _RequestHeaders.putIfAbsent("Accept-Encoding", () => "gzip, deflate, br");
  _RequestHeaders.putIfAbsent("referer", () => "https://www.morningstar.com/");
  _RequestHeaders.putIfAbsent("user-agent", () => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36");
  _RequestHeaders.putIfAbsent("authority", () => "www.morningstar.com");
}
return _RequestHeaders;
}
}
```

My pubspec.yaml :

```
name: dev1_stock_meter
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.7.0
  cloud_firestore:
  fluttertoast: ^3.0.4
  autocomplete_textfield: ^1.6.4
  html: ^0.13.3+3
  http: ^0.12.0
  date_format: ^1.0.6
  intl:
  csv: ^4.0.3
  xml:
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - images/logo.jpg

fonts:
  - family: GoogleSans
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/GoogleSans-Regular.ttf
        weight: 300
      - asset: fonts/GoogleSans-Bold.ttf
        weight: 400
```

Expected Result: 
The if conditions should get satisfied and the Element e should be put in the mapItemNameToElement.

Comment: check the length of each string your comparing. Maybe there is a CR on one value

Comment: @al76 I don't understand what you mean by CR. What are you trying to say.?

Comment: CR means carriage return. Sometimes string comparisons don't behave as expected because one value has control characters.

Comment: Check the actual code points that make up your strings. For example, try `print(ItemHeading.runes);`. My guess is that some of the invisible characters might be non-breaking spaces instead of plain spaces. If you look at the source, it contains `Dividends&nbsp;<span>INR<\/span>`. The `&nbsp;` entity is a non-breaking space (U+00A0) which looks like a space, but is not equal to it. The `innerText` will make your string contain that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html string has html entities

`Dividends INR  does not equal Dividends&nbsp;<span>INR`

use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html_unescape to decode itemheader before you do comparison

Comment: I checked the lengths of the two strings and found that the lengths are same. I tried to use the unescape library as well. Still no luck on this.

Comment: The `&nbsp;` entity has length one and looks like a space. It is not equal to a space, though. If you replace the correpsonding space in your pattern string with `\xA0`, then you will likely find that it starts matching.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The string contains \xA0. I replaced it with blank space and it is matching now. Your solution worked. Thanks.